# C/C++ Daemon in Linux: Silent Unexpected Termination

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, daemon

I have a program that creates a Daemon from a C/C++ program through the fork() method on a Linux system, and have been experiencing some program behaviors unknown to me. After I call a function checkConfiguration(), it will fail after the second iteration through the while loop it is in.

Here is the code in the context of where it is called...

```
  while (true) {
    // Read the buffer (inotify)
    i = 0;
    length = read( fd, buffer, BUF_LEN );
    if (length<0) {
      std::cerr << "ERROR\n";
      exit(1);
    }
    out->log("inotify buffer successfully read");

    checkConfiguration(parser, specs);
    out->log("configuration succeeded");
    ...
```

Here is the function source code...

```
void checkConfiguration (CmdParser parser, std::map<int, std::string> &specs) {
  // If SIGHUB received, reconfigure
  out->log("Begin of checkConfiguration");
  if (reconfigure) {
    // New Configure Values
    std::map<int, std::string> temp = parser.getArgs();
    configure(temp);
    // Reconfigure Specs
    specs[VERBOSE] = temp[VERBOSE];
    specs[LOGFILE] = temp[LOGFILE];
    specs[NUMVERSIONS] = temp[NUMVERSIONS];
    // Reset OutputDirector
    out->resetSpecs(specs);
    // Signal Completion of Reconfiguration
    reconfigure = false;
  }
  out->log("End of checkConfiguration reached");
}
```

Here are the log messages that I see during the execution of this program...

```
inotify buffer successfully read
begin of checkConfiguration
end of checkConfiguration reached
configuration succeeded
inotify buffer successfully read
begin of checkConfiguration
end of checkConfiguration reached
```

So from this we know that the Daemon fails... Somewhere between completing the function and returning to main()? I tested a print to stdout right after the function call as well to make sure my logging function wasn't failing in some way.

***Other Potentially Useful Information***

- The inotify read is checking if a file in a specific directory was modified.
- I'm not creating a new buffer for the inotify read, if that is needed.

I have absolutely no idea where to go from here. If I can provide any more information please let me know.

Comment: Run it in a debugger. Also may be worthwhile to try ASan, TSan, and UBSan.

Comment: If you see a crash in that location (as a function is returning), that might indicate that the destructor of an object on the stack is crashing, since the destructors of local variables will run at that point in the execution.  Dunno what that `CmdParser` object is that you are passing-by-value as your first argument, but if it has a destructor you might want to put some printf()'s into that destructor and see if all of them execute or not.

Comment: Can you try using `std::endl` rather than `"\n"`? The two are not identical: `std::endl` also flushes the output buffer, so you may not get the last message printed to console. `exit` will not necessarily call flush. I'm not sure if that applies to the global I/O streams (since it depends on their storage duration and I haven't payed close enough attention to know for certain), but it's a good practice regardless.

Comment: Aha! Yes, @JeremyFriesner 's hunch was right, I was deleting some very important pointer objects in the CmdParser object's destructor. Thanks everyone!

Comment: `std::cerr`. That's not a C program, that's definitely C++.